# Identifying monitor applet is running on, in a multi-monitor system

Tags: java, applet, position, screen, awt

I have *Applet* with a button running in a browser which when the button is clicked opens a JFrame.  I would like to set the JFrame location to be the centre of the screen of whichever monitor the browser was running in.  So if they only have one monitor the JFrame will open at the centre of this screen.  If they have two monitors and the browser is in the left monitor clicking the button would open the JFrame at the centre of the left monitor.  If the browser is in the right monitor display then clicking the button would cause the JFrame to open in the centre of the right monitor's display.

Currently I am using:-

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` to get a Toolkit object and then calling `Toolkit.getScreenSize()` to get the screen size and then working out the centre position from that.  This is always based on the left monitor regardless of where the browser is.

Also, I know this could be further complicated if a user happened to have a different resolution between their monitors.

Answer (score 2):

Get the [`GraphicsConfiguration` of the `JApplet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphicsConfiguration%28%29) and then pass that to the [constructor of your `JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#JFrame%28java.lang.String,%20java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration%29). You would also use that `GraphicsConfiguration` to get a [bounding rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getBounds%28%29) for centering.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back sooner on this.  I tried this and encountered the problem that if I have my browser in the left monitor and go to the webpage with the applet then I find that using getGraphicsConfiguration() on my applet returns a D3DGraphicsConfig with the following details:-

D3DGraphicsConfig[dev=D3DGraphicsDevice[screen=0],pixfmt=0]

If I get the Bounds on this object I get screen bounds of:-

java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=1024]

Comment: If my browser is in the right monitor and I go to the webpage with the applet then I find that using getGraphicsConfiguration() on my applet returns a D3DGraphicsConfig with the following details:-
D3DGraphicsConfig[dev=D3DGraphicsDevice[screen=1],pixfmt=0]
If I get the Bounds on this object I get screen bounds of:-
java.awt.Rectangle[x=1280,y=0,width=1280,height=1024]

Comment: So far so good.  Unfortunately if after loading the webpage with the applet I move the webpage to the other monitor then the D3DGraphicsConfig and Bounds returned reflect the details of the monitor that the applet was first loaded from, not from its current position.

Answer (score 1):

[`GraphicsDevice`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) will give you info on all screen devices.

It's designed to handle the exact scenario that you need, just take a look at the sample code.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It does show the details of the screen devices available to me, but it doesn't help me identify which monitor my applet is currently displayed on.  Any ideas on how to identify this?

Comment: `java.awt.Window` has a method called `getGraphicsConfiguration()`, which has a method called `getDevice()`, and if you're lucky, it returns the `GraphicsDevice` object your window is actually using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this has the same issue as above in which it identifies the screen as being the one which the applet first loaded on.  If the browser is moved to a different screen after the applet is loaded it still returns the screen as being the one it loaded on.  Is it possible that this is a bug in Java?

Comment: @Dave I should say so, yes. I would fully expect the `getDevice()` call on a window to return the device that actually displays the window, not the one that displayed it a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

For centering one can normally use JFrame.[setLocationRelativeTo(null)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29). Maybe it centers on the default screen? What if the argument is the applet?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case.  The setLocationRelativeTo(null) works with the first screen.